# Is there a way to take away certain words from returned text?

Tags: applescript

noob coder here,

I am trying to create a program that would remove certain words from a user returned sentence.

Heres what I got so far:

```
    set returnedSentence to display dialog "Welcome to SimpleScript Early Release (Beta)! To continue please enter your desired code/text." default answer "" buttons {"Go!", "Cancel"} default button 1

display dialog returnedSentance - "if" - "and" - "then" - "a" buttons {"ok", "Cancel"} default button 2
```

For example: If the user would enter the sentence: If I am hungry, then i would go to a restaurant.

Then the code should return I am hungry, i would go to restaurant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your concrete problem? What have you tried to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain AppleScript doesn't have regular expressions, but you can use `text item delimiters` to replace the desired text items with nothing/blanks.  For example:

```
set returnedSentence to text returned of (display dialog "Welcome to SimpleScript Early Release (Beta)! To continue please enter your desired code/text." default answer "" buttons {"Go!", "Cancel"} default button 1)

set trimList to {"if ", "and ", "then ", "a "} -- the text items to replace (note the trailing space to denote words)
set {tempTID, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, trimList} -- stash original delimiters (normally blank) and set new ones
set trimmedItems to text items of returnedSentence -- break the string apart
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to tempTID -- restore delimiters (normally blank)
set trimmedSentence to trimmedItems as text -- put the string back together

display dialog trimmedSentence buttons {"ok", "Cancel"} default button 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the regex library of your language to extract the part that does not contain de forbidden word.